# Prove that $\sup S \leq \inf T$.

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S$ and $T$ be nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with the following property: $s \leq t$ for all $s \in S$ and $t \in T$. **Prove that $\sup S \leq \inf T$.**

I have a question about this. We know that $\sup S \geq s$ for all $s \in S$, and $\inf T \leq t$ for all  $t \in T$. But $\sup S$ can be greater than $\inf T$. How can I prove this?

Comment: You also know other things about the supremum and the infimum of some set, isn't?

Comment: It looks as if you believe that we always have $\sup S\leqslant\inf T$ and also that we can have $\sup S>\inf T$. Am I right?

Comment: You’d be correct, if the only thing you knew about $\sup S$ and $\inf T$ was what was in your sentence starting “We know…”

Comment: @b00nheT yes, thank you so much, I found the answer in that question's answers. And thank you so much guys.